# Javascript keydown event doesn´t give me the char @ in EDGE

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working in a mentioning directive, basically when the user is typing in the input field ( a div with `contentEditable=true` in this case ), is gonna display a list of user for then insert the name of the user in a specific format, now the list is gonna displayed after the user press `@`, for chrome and firefox work just great but for EDGE and IE ( unfortunately i need to support ) doesn't work because in this case the `@` apparently doesn't exist.

now for the key press I'm using the `@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])`

**HostListener**

```
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) keyHandler(event: any, nativeElement: HTMLInputElement = this._element.nativeElement) {
    let val: string = getValue(nativeElement);
    let pos = getCaretPosition(nativeElement, this.iframe);
    let charPressed = this.keyCodeSpecified ? event.keyCode : event.key;
    if (!charPressed) {
      let charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
      if (!event.shiftKey && (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90)) {
        charPressed = String.fromCharCode(charCode + 32);
      } else if (event.shiftKey && charCode === KEY_2) {
        charPressed = this.triggerChar;
      } else {
        charPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode);
      }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == KEY_ENTER && event.wasClick && pos < this.startPos) {
      // put caret back in position prior to contenteditable menu click
      pos = this.startNode.length;
      setCaretPosition(this.startNode, pos, this.iframe);
    }
    // console.log('=== keyHandler', this.startPos, pos, val, charPressed, event);
    this.triggerList(event, charPressed, nativeElement, val, pos);
  }
```

Now as you can see I'm using `event.keycode` and `event.key` to get the key from the event keydown, I pass does values to the method `this.triggerList()`

that basically is gonna display the list of mentions options if and only if the user press `@` that is the trigger char ( `this.triggerChar` ).

**TriggerList Method**

```
  private triggerList(event, charPressed, nativeElement, val, pos): any {
    if (charPressed == this.triggerChar) {
      this.startPos = pos;
      this.startNode = (this.iframe ? this.iframe.contentWindow.getSelection() : window.getSelection()).anchorNode;
      // console.log('=== HERE CHAR', this.startNode, this.startPos);

      // check if mentioning is allowed based on the text before the mention start char
      if (!this.configService.appConfig.platform.EDGE) {
        let position = this.getHtmlCaretPosition(nativeElement);
        const charBefore = val[position - 1];

        if (charBefore == undefined || charBefore.trim() == '' || charBefore == ':') {
          this.log.trace('Start mentioning');
          this.stopSearch = false;
          this.searchString = null;
          this.showSearchList(nativeElement);
          this.updateSearchList();
        }
      } else {
        this.stopSearch = false;
        this.searchString = null;
        this.showSearchList(nativeElement);
        this.updateSearchList();
      }
    } else if (this.startPos >= 0 && !this.stopSearch) {
      if (pos <= this.startPos) {
        this.searchList.hidden = true;
      }
      // ignore shift when pressed alone, but not when used with another key
      else if (event.keyCode !== KEY_SHIFT && !event.metaKey && !event.altKey && !event.ctrlKey && pos > this.startPos) {
        if (event.keyCode === KEY_SPACE) {
          this.startPos = -1;
        } else if (event.keyCode === KEY_BACKSPACE && pos > 0) {
          pos--;
          if (pos == 0) {
            this.stopSearch = true;
          }
          this.searchList.hidden = this.stopSearch;
        } else if (!this.searchList.hidden) {
          if (event.keyCode === KEY_TAB || event.keyCode === KEY_ENTER) {
            this.stopEvent(event);
            this.searchList.hidden = true;
            // value is inserted without a trailing space for consistency
            // between element types (div and iframe do not preserve the space)
            let textValue = this.mentionSelect(this.searchList.activeItem);
            insertValue(nativeElement, this.startPos, pos, textValue, this.iframe);
            this.emitSelection(nativeElement);
            if (this.htmlStyling) {
              let quillElement = document.querySelector('.ql-editor');
              let innerHtml = quillElement.innerHTML;
              let strings = innerHtml.split(textValue);
              if (strings.length === 2) {
                innerHtml = `${strings[0]}<span id="mention${textValue.substring(1)}${strings.length - 1}" style="color: #0065FF; background: rgba(0,101,255,.2)">${textValue}</span> ${strings[1]}`;
              } else {
                let openSpan = false;
                innerHtml = strings.reduce((total, current, currentIndex) => {
                  if (current.indexOf(`mention${textValue.substring(1)}`) > 0) {
                    return `${total}${openSpan ? '</span> ' : ''}${current}${textValue}`;
                  } else if (openSpan) {
                    return `${total}</span> ${currentIndex < strings.length - 1 ? current + textValue : current}`;
                  } else {
                    openSpan = true;
                    return `${total}${current}<span id="mention${textValue.substring(1)}${strings.length - 1}" style="color: #0065FF; background: rgba(0,101,255,.2)">${textValue}`;
                  }
                }, '');
              }
              quillElement.innerHTML = innerHtml;
              // tslint:disable-next-line:no-angle-bracket-type-assertion
              let mentionElement: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById(`mention${textValue.substring(1)}${strings.length - 1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
              // tslint:disable-next-line:no-angle-bracket-type-assertion
              setCaretPosition(mentionElement.nextSibling as HTMLInputElement, 1);
            }
            // fire input event so angular bindings are updated
            if ('createEvent' in document) {
              let evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
              evt.initEvent('input', false, true);
              nativeElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
            this.startPos = -1;
            return false;
          } else if (event.keyCode === KEY_ESCAPE) {
            this.stopEvent(event);
            this.searchList.hidden = true;
            this.stopSearch = true;
            return false;
          } else if (event.keyCode === KEY_DOWN) {
            this.stopEvent(event);
            this.searchList.activateNextItem();
            return false;
          } else if (event.keyCode === KEY_UP) {
            this.stopEvent(event);
            this.searchList.activatePreviousItem();
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (event.keyCode === KEY_LEFT || event.keyCode === KEY_RIGHT) {
          this.stopEvent(event);
          return false;
        } else {
          let mention = val.substring(this.startPos + 1, pos);
          if (event.keyCode !== KEY_BACKSPACE) {
            mention += charPressed;
          }
          this.searchString = mention;
          this.searchTerm.emit(this.searchString);
          this.updateSearchList();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

now the issue here is that if the user to insert the char `@` need to use the combination of `ALT + Q` EDGE only detect `ALT` and then `Q`, compare to firefox and chrome that with the combination `ALT + Q` detect `@` for this reason the list is not display because the char never match.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode and https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html should be able to provide some hints.

Comment: Thanks so much i found the solution in the first link

Comment: Great! Maybe write a short self-answer then explaining what fixed the issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First i replace the event `keydown` for `keypress`, then where i save the char in the variable `charPress` i create a condition to check if the browser is EDGE or IE, and get char code using `event.charCode` and convert it in to string using `String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)` at the end looks like this.

```
  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) keyHandler(event: any, nativeElement: HTMLInputElement = this._element.nativeElement) {
    let val: string = getValue(nativeElement);
    let pos = getCaretPosition(nativeElement, this.iframe);
    let charPressed = this.keyCodeSpecified ? event.keyCode : event.key;
    if (this.configService.appConfig.platform.EDGE) {
      charPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    }
    ......
```